# Grouping Json Array Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, grouping

My source data is in standard JSON format. But I want format the data in grouping so that the Original data can be grouped by Catname and Catid.

Tough I have tried loadash library on the front end. But don't want to use it on front end.

```
var originalData = [
{
    "quesid": 1,
    "uoptid": 0,
    "catid": 1,
    "catname": "Soft Skill"
},
{
    "quesid": 2,
    "uoptid": 0,
    "catid": 1,
    "catname": "Soft Skill"
},
{
    "quesid": 3,
    "uoptid": 0,
    "catid": 2,
    "catname": "Technical"
},
{
    "quesid": 4,
    "uoptid": 0,
    "catid": 2,
    "catname": "Technical"
}
]
```

Desired as below:

```
        var transformData = [
        { 
          catname: "Soft Skill",
          catid : 1,
          ques : [ 
    {quesid : 1, uotp : 0 },
    {quesid : 2, uotp : 0 }
    ]
},
{
          catname: "Technical",
          catid : 2,
          ques : [ 
    {quesid : 3, uotp : 0 },
    {quesid : 4, uotp : 0 }
    ]
}
   ]
```

Comment: Post what you have tried thus far, and show where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.reduce`. If `ES6` is not a problem, it should be:

```js
var originalData = [{"quesid": 1, "uoptid": 0, "catid": 1, "catname": "Soft Skill"}, {"quesid": 2, "uoptid": 0, "catid": 1, "catname": "Soft Skill"}, {"quesid": 3, "uoptid": 0, "catid": 2, "catname": "Technical"},{"quesid": 4,"uoptid": 0,"catid": 2,"catname": "Technical"}];

var grouped = originalData.reduce((m, {quesid, uoptid, catid, catname}) => {
    var found = m.find(e => e.catid === catid);
    var quesItem = { quesid, uotp: uoptid };
    found ? found.ques.push(quesItem) : m.push({catname, catid, ques: [ quesItem ]});
    return m;
}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: This solution doest work and since it is using ES 6 , will create problem in IE 8

Comment: This doesn't work. It only shows one result in each group, rather than the two.

Comment: To be fair OP, you didn't mention a requirement to support a 9 year old browser.

Comment: @fubar It's fixed

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by creating a map of category ids and building the data by iterating over the source array. The resultant map can then be converted back to an array

Sample:

```
var originalData = [{
        "quesid": 1,
        "uoptid": 0,
        "catid": 1,
        "catname": "Soft Skill"
    },
    {
        "quesid": 2,
        "uoptid": 0,
        "catid": 1,
        "catname": "Soft Skill"
    },
    {
        "quesid": 3,
        "uoptid": 0,
        "catid": 2,
        "catname": "Technical"
    },
    {
        "quesid": 4,
        "uoptid": 0,
        "catid": 2,
        "catname": "Technical"
    }
];

var map = originalData.reduce(function (m, d) {
    if (!m[d.catname]) {
        m[d.catname] = {
            catname: d.catname,
            catid: d.catid,
            ques: []
        }
    }
    m[d.catname].ques.push({
        quesid: d.quesid,
        uopt: d.uoptid
    });
    return m;
}, {});
var transformData = Object.keys(map).map(function (key) {
    return map[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = OriginalData.reduce((p,c) => (p[c.catname] ? p[c.catname].push(c) : p[c.catname] = [c],p) ,{}),
newData = Object.keys(hash).map(k => ({catname: k, ques: hash[k]}));

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a straight forward approach with a hash table and some nested loops, one for the given data and one for getting a combined key.

```js
var data = [{ quesid: 1, uoptid: 0, catid: 1, catname: "Soft Skill" }, { quesid: 2, uoptid: 0, catid: 1, catname: "Soft Skill" }, { quesid: 3, uoptid: 0, catid: 2, catname: "Technical" }, { quesid: 4, uoptid: 0, catid: 2, catname: "Technical" }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    keys = ["catid", "catname"],
    i, j, key, o,
    grouped = [];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    key = "";
    o = data[i];
    for (j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        key += (key && "|") + o[keys[j]];
    }
    if (!hash[key]) {
        hash[key] = { catname: o.catname, catid: o.catid, ques: [] };
        grouped.push(hash[key]);
    }
    hash[key].ques.push({ quesid: o.quesid, uotp: o.uoptid });
}

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```